# Angular and Spring webflux - ERROR TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).request is not a function

Tags: angular, server-sent-events

I have backend spring application that sends out api response as webflux. I am trying to save the data by making use of **EventSource** . When I call the service, I get exception in the browser console as

```
ERROR TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).request is not a function
    at connect (eventsource.js:139)
    at new EventSource (eventsource.js:253)
    at Observable._subscribe (api.service.ts:88)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at FlightsOagService.getFlightsOag (flights-oag.service.ts:24)
    at ExhaustMapSubscriber.project (flights.effects.ts:18)
    at ExhaustMapSubscriber.tryNext (exhaustMap.js:37)
    at ExhaustMapSubscriber._next (exhaustMap.js:30)
    at ExhaustMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
```

My service call code looks like this

```
return new Observable<string>(obs => {
  const es = new EventSource(`${this.Url}${path}`, options);
  es.addEventListener('message', (evt) => {
    console.log(evt.data);
    obs.next(evt.data);
  });
  return () => es.close();
});
```

Can anyone help with what is wrong here. Thank you in advance.